# How to configure Geany to show line numbers with latin instead of arabic numerals

Tags: ubuntu, text-editor, geany

How to change Geany settings in a way to show latin numerals instead of arabic numerals

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The font using for the line numbers is based on font you configured for editor widget. This can be changed via Edit->Preferences->Interface->Editor. Changing your font to some with latin numeral instead of arabic could work.

This being said: This might will also change the appearance of numerals inside your source code.

(I wasn't able to reproduce the screenshot you made even with running Geany on ar_AE for testing purpose and playing around with different fonts)